# Comparing two objects in typescript and do assignment operation in one of the object

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I have an Object which looks like below. It is called as **selectedFilters**.

```
selectedFilters = [
  {columnName: "gender", values: ["Male"]},
  {columnName: "approximate_age_band", values: ["18-29", "30-39", "40-49"]}, 
  {columnName: "custom_flag2", values: ["1686", "2245", "2255"]}
]
```

I have one object named as **menuOptions** which has multiple properties such as mode, currentSelection, filters, segments etc. Below is how it looks.

```
{toggles: {…}, modes: {…}, viewOptions: {…}, segments: Array(3), filters: {…}, …} currentSelection: {default: "percent", order: 1, label: "View", type: "filter", value: "total", …} filters: {mainFilters: Array(3), standard: Array(4), custom: Array(4), maxFilters: 4} modes: {selected: "trends", options: Array(1)} segments: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Now I have to take **menuOptions.filters** and apply some logic into it. The structure of **menuOptions.filters** look like below.

[image]

I want loop through **menuOptions.filters.standard**.

```
menuOptions.filters.standard = [
  {columnName: "gender", selected: null},
  {columnName: "approximate_age_band", selected: null},
  {columnName: "custom_flag2", selected: null}
]
```

I want to compare **selectedFilters** with **menuOptions.filters.standard**. If the column name matches, then insert a new property to **menuOptions.filters.standard** object so that it will look like below.

```
menuOptions.filters.standard = [
  {columnName: "gender", selected: "Male"},
  {columnName: "approximate_age_band", selected: ""18-29,30-39,40-49""},
  {columnName: "custom_flag2", selected: "1686,2245,2255"}
]
```

I have tried to do below way.

```
let i = 0;
selectedFilterList.forEach(function (choice) {

    if(this.menuOptions.filters.standard[i]['columnName'] === choice['columnName']){
        this.menuOptions.filters.standard[i]['selected'] = choice['values'];
        i = i+1;
    }
});
```

But the above logic is throwing error: core.js:4002 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'menuOptions' of undefined. However outside the loop I am able to access this.menuOptions. Inside it's throwing error.

Comment: Outside the loop, the instance of 'this' is different and inside of loop it is different. In functions, the 'this' refers to the instance of an object of class, So the scope of 'this' in  outside function is not same as the inside of forEach loop. You can assign your 'this' to some other variable name. For example, assign var me = this; outside of forEach. And use me.menuOptions inside your forEach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `arrow function` (=>) instead `function` :)

```
let i = 0;

selectedFilterList.forEach((choice) => {

  if(this.menuOptions.filters.standard[i]['columnName'] === choice['columnName']){
      Convert the values to string and do assignment
    i = i+1;
  }
});
```

I hope It'll help you! Be happy and Have a clean code :)

Comment: Probably the way I am doing loop is not the issue, but I am not able to access this.menuOptions inside the loop. It is throwing error as Cannot read property 'menuOptions' of undefined. Is there any restriction in Angular that we can't access an object inside the loop of another object ? Because outside of the loop it is accessible.

Comment: I think You lose you context (this) when you user `function (choice) {` because `function` has its own context (this) :)

Comment: Just try to use `=>`

Comment: Try to use example of code which I provide above.

Comment: Yeah I am not getting the error anymore, but the logic is not working as expected. I mean  this.menuOptions.filters.standard[i]['columnName'] and choice['columnName'] are not getting compared correctly and not giving the expected result.

Comment: I have edited my logic in main post, just take a look what exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: Just wrap the `if(...){...}` in a `while (i < this.menuOptions.filters.standard.length){}`

Comment: I think You have some problems in your code logic, we fixed your problem with THIS and now you should fix your code logic error :)